# Добавить десять уникальных элементов

Tags: java, android, list

Постараюсь преподнести вопрос корректно (открыт для замечаний/правок).

Начну пожалуй с начала. Есть кнопка по нажатию на которую открывается диалог. В диалоге пользователь может вставить ссылку из vimeo и youtube.
После того, как ссылка вставлена в поле диалога и нажата кнопка "OK", в методе getIdUrl вытаскивается id из ссылки, после чего добавляется сама картинка из видео(preview) - пользователь(грубо говоря) видит как добавилась картинка из этого видео(следовательно видео загружено).

На данный момент, приложение реализовано так, что пользователь может добавлять n-ое кол-во видео(с одинаковыми ссылками), что само собой неприемлемо.

Задача заключается в поиске решения данной проблемы, а именно:

- Добавить возможность для пользователя добавления не более 10 файлов.
- Если ссылка повторяется(url видео), не добавлять его.

Отрывок диалога:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ОК", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String string = input.getText().toString();
            getIdUrl(string, pos);
        }
```

И часть реализации метода getIdUrl для youtube:

```
void getIdUrl(String url, int position) {
    String video_id = "";
    String expression = "";
    if (url != null && url.trim().length() > 0 && url.matches(".*\\byoutube\\b.*")) {
        expression = "^.*((youtu.be" + "\\/)" + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*";

        CharSequence input = url;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
            if (groupIndex1 != null && groupIndex1.length() == 11)
                video_id = groupIndex1;
        }
        ImageUpload imageUpload = new ImageUpload();
        imageUpload.setLoadImage(true);
        OutputMetadata outputMetadata = new OutputMetadata();
        outputMetadata.setVideoUrl("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg");
        outputMetadata.setFilename("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg");
        imageUpload.setOutputMetadata(outputMetadata);
        controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().add(imageUpload);
        adapterForm.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Дополнительно к разбору:
Модель VideoUpload

```
public class VideoUpload {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("videoUrl")
@Expose
String videoUrl;
@SerializedName("user_portrait_huge")
@Expose
private String userPortraitHuge;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;

public String getUserPortraitHuge() {
    return userPortraitHuge;
}
```

Прописаны все get'ры и set'ры.

Метод contains(во фрагменте)

```
    public boolean contains(VideoUpload newVideoUpload) {
    for (VideoUpload videoUpload : videoUploads) {
        if (videoUpload.getUrl().equals(newVideoUpload.getUrl()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `List.get()` ни в коем случае не добавляет элемент в список. Он наоборот - достает его. Но все равно, не понятно, куда же вы хотите добавить, и что.

Comment: @metalurgus на данный момент я получаю одну картинку(preview) из видео которое обработал, после чего не могу добавлять более(пропадает сама кнопка, т.к. предпологаю, что из за get(0) добавляется одна позиция), а мне необходимо увеличить кол-во добавленных картинок. Впихнуть что то типо list add наверное.

Comment: Ну, так не прячте кнопку, в чем проблема?

Comment: В данный момент ваша проблема не ясна. Попробуйте сформулировать как-то иначе. Типа "у меня есть массив адресов видеофайлов и я хочу по нажатию на кнопку скачать сразу все. Но у меня получается только один файл скачать."

Comment: Циклы служат для того чтобы делать какую либо повторяющуюся операцию N раз, по этому исходя из туманного объяснения которое вы предоставили я вам советую воспользоваться циклом, для тех "темных ритуалов" которые вы пытаетесь провернуть;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Постановка задачи:

По ссылке на видео с `youtube.com` или `vimeo.com` получить превью видео и отобразить его в списке на экране.

При этом:

- Максимально можно добавить 10 видео;
- Не добавлять уже существующие видео.

Превью можно добавить по трем типам ссылок:

- `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX`
- `https://youtu.be/XXXXXXXXXXX`
- `https://vimeo.com/XXXXXXXXX`

### Решение:

Создаем `activity_video_preview.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_video_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/video_preview_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Создаем `item_video_preview.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_video_preview_image_view"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_video_preview_link_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_video_preview_image_view"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_video_preview_link_preview_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_video_preview_image_view"
            android:layout_below="@id/item_video_preview_link_text_view"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Создаем (для удобства) интерфейс `VideoTypes`:

```
public interface VideoTypes {
    int TYPE_UNKNOWN = 0;
    int TYPE_YOUTUBE = 1;
    int TYPE_VIMEO = 2;
}
```

Создаем класс модели данных `VideoPreview`:

```
public class VideoPreview {
    private String mVideoLink;
    private String mPreviewLink;

    public VideoPreview(String videoLink, String previewLink) {
        mVideoLink = videoLink;
        mPreviewLink = previewLink;
    }

    public String getVideoLink() {
        return mVideoLink;
    }

    public String getPreviewLink() {
        return mPreviewLink;
    }
}
```

Создаем класс `VideoMethods` для обработки ссылок на видео:

```
public class VideoMethods implements VideoTypes {

    public static int getLinkType(String link) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^https:\\/\\/www\\.(youtube\\.com)\\/watch\\?v=[\\w-]{11}$|^https:\\/\\/(youtu\\.be)\\/[\\w-]{11}$|^https:\\/\\/(vimeo\\.com)\\/[0-9]*$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(link);
        if (!matcher.matches())
            return TYPE_UNKNOWN;

        for (int i=1; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            if (matcher.group(i) != null) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                        return TYPE_YOUTUBE;
                    case 3:
                        return TYPE_VIMEO;
                    default:
                        return TYPE_UNKNOWN;
                }
            }
        }
        return TYPE_UNKNOWN;
    }

    public static String getId(String link) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^https:\\/\\/www\\.youtube\\.com\\/watch\\?v=([\\w-]{11})$|^https:\\/\\/youtu\\.be\\/([\\w-]{11})$|^https:\\/\\/vimeo\\.com\\/([0-9]*)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(link);
        matcher.matches();

        for (int i=1; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            if (matcher.group(i) != null) {
                return matcher.group(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Адаптер для `RecyclerView`:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<VideoPreview> mItems;
    private Context mContext;

    public DataAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_video_preview, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.mPreviewLinkTextView.setText(mItems.get(i).getVideoLink());
        viewHolder.mPreviewLinkPreviewTextView.setText(mItems.get(i).getPreviewLink());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mItems.get(i).getPreviewLink()).resize(120, 90).into(viewHolder.mPreviewImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public void addItem(VideoPreview videoPreview) {
        mItems.add(videoPreview);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public boolean contains(VideoPreview newVideoPreview) {
        for (VideoPreview videoPreview : mItems) {
            if (videoPreview.getVideoLink().equals(newVideoPreview.getVideoLink()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView mPreviewImageView;
        TextView mPreviewLinkTextView;
        TextView mPreviewLinkPreviewTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            mPreviewImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_video_preview_image_view);
            mPreviewLinkTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_video_preview_link_text_view);
            mPreviewLinkPreviewTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_video_preview_link_preview_text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и, наконец, `VideoPreviewActivity`:

```
public class VideoPreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VideoTypes {

    private RecyclerView mVideoPreviewRecyclerView;
    private EditText mAddEditText;
    private Button mAddButton;

    private OkHttpClient httpClient;
    private DataAdapter mDataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_preview);

        mVideoPreviewRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.video_preview_recycler_view);
        mAddEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_edit_text);
        mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);

        mVideoPreviewRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.video_preview_recycler_view);
        mVideoPreviewRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mVideoPreviewRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        mDataAdapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        mVideoPreviewRecyclerView.setAdapter(mDataAdapter);

        httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mDataAdapter.getItemCount() == 10) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can not add more than 10 videos!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                String videoLink = mAddEditText.getText().toString();
                int videoType = VideoMethods.getLinkType(videoLink);

                if (videoType == TYPE_UNKNOWN) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect link!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                mAddEditText.getText().clear();

                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) VideoPreviewActivity.this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(VideoPreviewActivity.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

                String videoId = VideoMethods.getId(videoLink);

                switch (videoType) {
                    case TYPE_YOUTUBE:
                        VideoPreview videoPreview = new VideoPreview(videoLink, "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/1.jpg");
                        if (!mDataAdapter.contains(videoPreview)) {
                            mDataAdapter.addItem(videoPreview);
                            mVideoPreviewRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mDataAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This video already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        break;

                    case TYPE_VIMEO:
                        try {
                            getVimeoPreview(videoLink, videoId);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something going wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void getVimeoPreview(final String videoLink, final String videoId) throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/" + videoId + ".xml")
                .build();

        httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something going wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                String s = response.body().string();

                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<thumbnail_small>(.*)<\\/thumbnail_small>");
                final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
                m.find();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        VideoPreview videoPreview = new VideoPreview(videoLink, m.group(1));
                        if (!mDataAdapter.contains(videoPreview)) {
                            mDataAdapter.addItem(videoPreview);
                            mVideoPreviewRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mDataAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This video already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Не забывает добавить в `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

В итоге получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, на самом деле отличный ответ,  помог разобраться во многих нюансах.
На данный момент стараюсь хоть и частично, но перенести реализацию в свой проект. К примеру в Вашем методе contains возникла загвоздка, я также обращаюсь к своей модели типа String, а он мне выдаёт required java.lang.string , found ...image.VideoUpload. Возможно подскажете в чем может быть загвоздка?

Comment: Проблема в несоответствии типов. С помощью `equals(...)` я сравниваю ссылки на видео (типа `String`) одного объекта с другим. А Вы?

Comment: Да, это я понял. Но у меня в модели также getVideoUrl типа String, вот собственно и не понимаю почему такая ошибка.

Comment: Покажите Вашу модель данных и метод `contains(...)` адаптера.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: А на какой строчке это возникает?

Comment: for (VideoUpload videoUpload : videoUploads) {
Подчёркивает "VideoUpload videoUpload"

Comment: У меня в адаптере `private ArrayList<VideoPreview> mItems;`, а у Вас?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46623/discussion-between-vadim-morozov-and-post-zeew).

Answer (score 1):

Мое понимание проблемы таково:

У автора есть метод `public void success(ArrayList<VideoUpload> videoUpload, Response response)`, в этом методе он хочет изменить данные `controlList.get(pos).getImageUploads()`, который, видимо, является `ArrayList<SomeObject>` в соответствии с полученным `ArrayList<VideoUpload> videoUpload`.

На данный момент он изменяет данные только первого элемента `controlList.get(pos).getImageUploads()` в соответствии с первым элементом `ArrayList<VideoUpload> videoUpload` (о чем говорит вызов метода `get(...)` у обоих списков с параметром `0`).

Исходя из всего вышесказанного следует, что размеры `ArrayList<VideoUpload> videoUpload` и `controlList.get(pos).getImageUploads()` должны совпадать.

Таким образом, решением проблемы будет такой код метода `success(...)`:

```
@Override
public void success(ArrayList<VideoUpload> videoUpload, Response response) {

    for(int i=0; i<videoUpload.size(); i++) {
        controlList.get(pos).getImageUploads().get(i).setLoadImage(true);
        controlList.get(pos).getImageUploads().get(i).getOutputMetadata().setVideoUrl(videoUpload.get(i).getUserPortraitHuge());
        controlList.get(pos).getImageUploads().get(i).getOutputMetadata().setFilename(videoUpload.get(i).getUserPortraitHuge());
    }
    adapterForm.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d("succes", "sisisihjdf");
}
```

---

**UPD.**

```
public void success(ArrayList<VideoUpload> videoUpload, Response response) {
        ImageUpload imageUpload = new ImageUpload();
        imageUpload.setLoadImage(true);
        imageUpload.getOutputMetadata().setVideoUrl(videoUpload.get().getUserPortraitHuge());
        imageUpload.getOutputMetadata().setFilename(videoUpload.get().getUserPortraitHuge());
}
```

> Подскажите какой value можно вставить в значение get(?)?

Любое целое число `i`, такое, что `0 <= i < videoUpload.size()` в зависимости от того, какой элемент списка `videoUpload` Вы хотите получить.

Comment: У Вас очень непонятный (*по крайней мере для меня*) контекст. Как вариант – отредактируйте Ваш вопрос таким образом: сначала полно и явно сформулируйте Вашу задачу на словах (без кода). Потом **по частям** опишите (с кодом), как Вы эту задачу решаете. Ну и в конце напишите что не получается.

Comment: Спасибо, на этот раз постарался учесть все моменты. Провёл работу над ошибками, дополнив решение, после чего обновил вопрос.

Comment: Вас устроит если я напишу Вам решение Вашей задачи с нуля?

Comment: Неужели в моём коде все настолько плохо?( Плюс не уверен, что Ваш код будет работать у меня, на данный момент это в приоритете(хотя не скрою, интерес к Вашей реализации несомненно есть). Просто боюсь, что не смогу его до реализовать, если вдруг.

Comment: Я не особо люблю перерабатывать объемные фрагменты чужого кода, особенно в предположении, что там что-то может работать неправильно.

Comment: Ну на данном моменте код нуждается лишь в добавлении функционала(к сожалению которому не знаю пока как подойти) ну и в будущем рефакторинга, но это уже другая совсем история. Плюс если все же решитесь попробовать написать с 0, столкнётесь с проблемой вытаскивания id в vimeo(я реализовывал через ретрофит к примеру). Ну и опять же, буду только рад Вашей помощи. Возможно это будет полезным не только мне, учитывая кол-во просмотров этого вопроса.

Comment: Добавил еще один ответ.